# "Factory Reset"-Strategy with an UEFI-x86-GPIO-Board

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

What would be the "right" strategy for this use-case?

1. x86_64-platform with UEFI
2. 40-Pin GPIO available
3. Ubuntu/Debian and Yocto-Custom-Build available (by manufacturer) for that platform/board
4. eMMC and SSD available

The goal is to have a working Debian-system on SSD which should be standardized loaded.
At the same time there should be an option to do a "factory reset" by i.e. pressing a GPIO-button during startup process. "factory reset" means that the Debian-system on SSD will be completely wiped and replaced with (new partition? and) "new" prepared Image (saved at eMMC).

The problem is that the GPIO-button-press recognition would need loading a linux with its kernel/drivers.

So my "strategy" would be loading a seperate linux at eMMC by UEFI boot order which could recognize the GPIO-button-state and normally without button press it would change UEFI boot order to boot first the SSD and restart. Then the Debian-system (SSD) would boot at first and at startup would again change the UEFI boot order to boot next time first again the eMMC-Linux (which could recognize the eventual button press or normally load the SSD again).

The problem is that if the Debian-linux on SSD fails of what reason ever, it can not change the boot order back to the eMMC-linux at startup.

So, what would be the "right" way to solve that problem? Am I thinking this too simple or too overcomplicated? What are the options in that case?

Comment: I wonder if `efibootmgr` on the *eMMC-linux* would help

Comment: Yes, that is the solution for the eMMC-linux. There would the boot order changed to boot the SSD-linux. But the problem is what happens then. While/after booting the SSD-linux the boot order would need to change back to boot the eMMC-linux (at next startup). The SSD-linux could use efibootmgr to do that. But the SSD-linux could possibly fail. Actually I'm exploring UEFI-Shell. But I'm new to that.

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation for `efibootmgr` specifically the `--bootnext` option

Comment: I thought I read the docs but obviously I didn't read it thoroughly. That is indeed the answer! Thank you so much for your hint!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that is what you wanted. I assume that while the condition is to boot the SSD (GPIO button not pressed?), you will boot eMMC which reboots to SSD, every time?

Comment: It is what I wanted. By standard: first booting the eMMC-linux. This will check for button-press. If there is no button-press "bootnext the SSD-linux" and reboot. So the SSD-linux will be started then.
At next startup/reboot (after booting the SSD-linux) the same procedure because of restored default boot order (eMMC-linux first). And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above I've got the answer from Jaromanda X.

`efibootmgr` option `--bootnext` exactly does what I wanted to achieve.